# Proof of series representation of inverse of sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, summation, inverse

Is there a proof that $(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}BA^{-1} + A^{-1}BA^{-1}BA^{-1} - \cdots$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Why do you think this is true?  How far have you gotten with it?  What assumptions are you making?  It's false when $A=B=I$, even though $A,B,$ and $A+B$ are invertible.

Comment: I am trying to prove $\|(I+A)^{-1}\| \leq \frac{1}{1-\|A\|}$ when $\|A\| < 1$. If I could represent the LHS as a series then that would bring me closer to the proof. I should have said is it true that... Rather than ask for a proof.

Comment: It's easy to see that it's true when all inverses exist and the right-hand converges.  Just multiply the right-hand side by $A+B$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no proof because of the following counter example:

Take

$A=\left[\begin{matrix}
1&0\\
0&0\\
\end{matrix}\right]$

$B=\left[\begin{matrix}
0&0\\
0&1\\
\end{matrix}\right]$

We have $A+B= \left[\begin{matrix}
1&0\\
0&1\\
\end{matrix}\right]$ $\Rightarrow$ $(A+B)^{-1}= \left[\begin{matrix}
1&0\\
0&1\\
\end{matrix}\right]$

But $A$ is not invertible, so $A^{-1}$ is not defined.